# Prevent state reset

Tags: reactjs

I have an application that allows the user to upload photos, to edit them (crop, zoom and rotate) and to download.

I'm trying to add a preview mode, so the user can see how the file he's downloading will look like.

What I did works fine except for one thing - when the user clicks on the `Clear Preview` button the photos go back to their original state (the state is being reset on `Clear Preview` button click),
without keeping the changes the user made to them.

Any idea what am I missing and how to prevent the state reset?

```
export default function ImagesGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles({})
  const {
    photos,
    preparePhotos,
    checkUnusedSuppliedTags,
    usedTagsList,
    suppliedTags
  } = useContext(SitePhotosContext)

  const taggedPhotos = photos.filter(photo => photo.tags.length)
  const pages = Math.ceil(taggedPhotos.length / 6)
  const [isPreviewMode, setIsPreviewMode] = useState(false)
  const [preparedPhotos, setPreparedPhotos] = useState([])
  const renderedPhotos = isPreviewMode ? preparedPhotos : photos
  let countColor: TypographyProps['color'] = 'initial'

  const tags = usedTagsList.concat(
    checkUnusedSuppliedTags(usedTagsList, suppliedTags)
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    preparePhotos(photos).then(photos => setPreparedPhotos(photos))
  }, [photos])

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="sticky" color="default">
        <Toolbar>
          {!isPreviewMode ? (
            <div className={classes.toolbarText}>
              <Typography
                variant="h6"
                color={countColor}
                className={classes.pageCount}
              >
                {`${taggedPhotos.length} Tagged Photos / ${pages} Pages`}
              </Typography>
              {taggedPhotos.length === 0 && (
                <Typography
                  variant="body2"
                  color={countColor}
                  className={classes.instructions}
                >
                  Tag some photos to generate a report
                </Typography>
              )}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <DownloadPreflightModal
              photos={preparedPhotos}
              usedTagsList={usedTagsList}
            />
          )}
          <DownloadAndPreview
            isPreviewMode={isPreviewMode}
            setIsPreviewMode={setIsPreviewMode}
            tags={tags}
          />
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Grid
        container
        justify="flex-start"
        spacing={2}
        className={classes.imageGrid}
      >

        {renderedPhotos.map(photo => (
          <Grid
            item
            xs={12}
            sm={6}
            md={isPreviewMode ? 6 : 4}
            key={photo.id}
            className={isPreviewMode ? classes.imageInternalGrid : ''}
          >
            <Image photo={photo} mode={isPreviewMode ? 'preview' : 'editor'} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`DownloadAndPreview` component:

```
export default function DownloadAndPreview({
  isPreviewMode,
  setIsPreviewMode,
  tags
}) {
  const classes = useStyles({})
  const generatorRef = useRef()
  const {photos} = useContext(SitePhotosContext)

  return (
    <>
      {!isPreviewMode ? (
        <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => setIsPreviewMode(true)}>
          Preview
          <VisibilityIcon />
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <Button
            color="inherit"
            onClick={() => setIsPreviewMode(false)}
            className={classes.previewModeBtn}
          >
            Clear Preview
            <ClearIcon />
          </Button>
          <Button
            color="inherit"
            onClick={() => {
              downloadDoc(generatorRef, photos, tags)
            }}
          >
            Download
          </Button>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

`<Image />` component:

```
export default function Image({photo, mode}: {photo: ImageItem; mode: string}) {
  const classes = useStyles({})
  const {
    setImageEditData
  } = useContext(SitePhotosContext)

  return mode === 'editor' ? (
    <Paper>
      {!photo.src && (
        <div className={classes.loading}>Loading {photo.data?.name}...</div>
      )}

      <div>
        <ImageEditor
          photo={photo}
          onEditComplete={editData => {
            setImageEditData(photo.id, editData)
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </Paper>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <img src={photo.src} className={classes.img} />
      <label>{photo.tags.join(' / ')}</label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`<ImageEditor />` component:

```
export default function ImageEditor({
  photo,
  onEditComplete,
  showControls
}: editorProps) {
  const classes = useStyles({})
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({x: 0, y: 0})

  const [rotation, setRotation] = useState(0)
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1)

  const onCropComplete = useCallback(
    (croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => {
      const editSettings: editData = {crop: croppedAreaPixels, rotate: rotation}
      onEditComplete(editSettings)
    },
    [rotation, onEditComplete]
  )

  return (
    <>
      <Box className={classes.cropContainer}>
        <Cropper
          image={photo.src}
          aspect={maxImageWidth / maxImageHeight}
          crop={crop}
          rotation={rotation}
          zoom={zoom}
          zoomWithScroll={false}
          onCropChange={setCrop}
          onRotationChange={setRotation}
          onCropComplete={onCropComplete}
          onZoomChange={setZoom}
        />
      </Box>
      {showControls && (
        <Box display="flex" className={classes.controls}>
          <IconButton
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => setRotation(rotation => rotation - 90)}
          >
            <RotateLeftIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Box display="inline-flex" width="100%">
            <ImageIcon
              fontSize="small"
              color="action"
              className={classes.imageIcon}
            />
            <Slider
              className={classes.slider}
              value={zoom}
              min={1}
              max={3}
              step={0.1}
              onChange={(e, zoom) => setZoom(zoom)}
            />
            <ImageIcon
              fontSize="large"
              color="action"
              className={classes.imageIcon}
            />
          </Box>
          <IconButton
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => setRotation(rotation => rotation + 90)}
          >
            <RotateRightIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Box>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

`context` functions:

```
  const preparePhotos = async (photos: PhotoList) => {
    const res = photos
      .filter(photo => photo.tags.length)
      .sort(sortByPriority)

    if (res.length % 2) res.pop()

    const edittedPhotos = await Promise.all(res.map(editImage))
    return edittedPhotos
  }

  const setImageEditData = (id, editData) => {
    setPhotos(photos =>
      photos.map(photo => {
        if (photo.id === id) {
          return {...photo, editData}
        }
        return photo
      })
    )
  }

  const editImage = async (image: ImageItem) => {
    if (!image.editData) return image
    const {crop, rotate} = image.editData
    const edittedImage = await cropAndRotateImage(image.src, crop, rotate)
    return {
      ...image,
      src: edittedImage,
      dimensions: {width: crop.width, height: crop.height}
    }
  }
```

Expected behavior is similar to this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-easy-crop-custom-image-demo-y09komm059?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js:3141-3151

After the user closes the preview modal the photo stay in the same position it was - before clicking on the preview button. (What by me - it doesn't)

Comment: Keep your image component separate and once image is uploaded then set that value into your parent component.

Comment: First you are not showing the relevant code... You talk about "Clear Preview" but you do not show it the component where that happens. Second you are showing a different set of photos here " const renderedPhotos = isPreviewMode ? preparedPhotos : photos"... My guess is that when you change isPreviewMode the component renders again and now it uses photos instead of preparedPhotos

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Thank you, I have updated my code, `preparedPhotos` is the images with changes we do to the pictures before downloading (`preparePhotos` function), photos is the original state, the one that actually keeps the `editImage` data. When the `Preview` button is being clicked the state isn't being reset, just on `Clear Preview` click.

Comment: The code behaves as expected.  When you click on clear preview the screens show the photos as they were before the clear preview.... because you never actually persist the changes to the actual photos.

Comment: Yes I do, I see it on the state: `photos` is being passed to the `<Image />` component when it's on editor mode. I see the `editData` on the state until the `Clear Preview` is being clicked.

Comment: @user3378165, as @JonathanAlfaro said when `Clear Preview` clicked you end up with `{`**`photos`**`.map(photo => ... <Image photo={photo} mode={'editor'} /> ...)}` And if before that there was some `photo.editData` but after `Clear Preview` there is no `photo.editData`, then the error is elsewhere, not in the code you've provided. Nothing here changes `photos` or anything inside `photos`

Comment: @x00 I have edited my question to include all relevant code.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I have edited my question to include all relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question still lacks some vital information. But let me guess...

1. Let's assume that you're using https://github.com/ricardo-ch/react-easy-crop (It's just the first library I came across, but even if you're using another library, I suppose, they mostly work the same way).
2. If so, then on every rerender `<Cropper>` calls `onCropComplete`. And it rerenders every time you switch into `editor`-mode.
3. On image load `react-easy-crop` sets `crop`, `rotation` and `zoom` to respective values passed to `<Cropper>` which you hold in `<ImageEditor>` component's state.
4. But here

   ```
   function Image(...) {
     ...
     return mode === 'editor' ? ( ... <ImageEditor ... /> ... ) : ( ... )
   }
   ```

   you loose `<ImageEditor>` component's state on every mode switch.
5. As a result: when you switch from `preview`-mode into `editor`-mode `<Cropper>` receives default values for `crop`, `rotation` and `zoom`, calls `onCropComplete` and your implementation of `onCropComplete` sets `editData` to these default values.

There are several ways to fix this. But the main issue, as I see it, is that you don't have a single source of truth for photo's `editData`. So I think you should get rid of `<ImageEditor>` component's state and instead pass `editData` to the `<Cropper>`. Like so:

```
<Cropper
  image    = {photo.src}
  crop     = {photo.editData.crop}
  rotation = {photo.editData.rotation}
  zoom     = {photo.editData.zoom}
  ...
/>
```

<sup>You don't have a minimal reproducible example, so I can't test it. For this to works you should probably at least add some default values for `photo.editData`</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I spent so many hours to figure it out and finally thanks to your answer I was able to get it to work, I'm sorry I missed awarding the bounty, I'll start a new one. As I can't start a 150 bounty anymore (it only starts from a 300 bounty) I'll start a 300 bounty and will award it in 24 hours- when it opens for awaring. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. By the way, what crop lib are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I think you could blob your image modified, then save it to localStorage and, when user exit from preview mode, show image blobbed instead of original `photo`.

I try to explain better: lets say you have this image in preview mode and user zooms it. So now original image is modified. Then, user clicks `Clear Preview` button. Just before call `setIsPreviewMode(false)` you could store modified image using, for example, [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image). Something like:

```
domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById("ImageModifiedId"))
        .then(function (blob) {
            // here you have the image modified blobbed into blob item
            // then localStorage.setItem("ImageKey", blob);
            // and finally setIsPreviewMode(false)
        });
```

Ok now the last step, instead of passing to `<Image>` always the same `photo`, you could verify if there is a modifed photo in your localStorage and, if there is, load `localStorage.getItem("ImageKey")` into `<Image>`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not passing the same `photo` to `<Image>`: `  const renderedPhotos = isPreviewMode ? preparedPhotos : photos`, I'm trying to understand what in me code reset the `photos` state by clicking `Clear Preview`

Comment: Ciao, oh ok. In the meantime, I edited your codesandbox appling my suggestion. Take a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-easy-crop-custom-image-demo-1kq2s?file=/src/index.js). What do you think? Let me know if it's sufficient, otherwise I try to inspect better your code

Comment: Thank you, I don't get the point of doing that- the codesandbox I mentioned on my question is something I found online and I mentioned it as an example of what I _want my code_ to look like, I don't get why my code act differently than the one on the codesandbox.

Comment: Ciao, the point is, as you can see, I can get the image modified from imgDialg.js and show it on index.js . Anyway, I understood that this question is strictly related to your code. The only thing is that is quite difficult to reproduce your problem from example code you show. Can you provide a github repo or a codesandbox in which I can work better?